# Update query statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax, sql-update

I found out something strange which works

```
Update **X** SET field = 'bla'
from **X**
```

..which doesn't really make sense

Answer (score 1):

This general syntax is usually used for joining tables when updating (i.e., you want to update column c1 in table t1 based on column c2 in table t2). The general for is

```sql
UPDATE 
    t1
SET 
    t1.c1 = t2.c2, -- Just an example
    t1.c3 = 'something else' -- etc...
FROM 
    t1
[INNER | LEFT] JOIN t2 ON join_condition
```

On you example, you don't have a `join` clause, so it may look a bit funny, but as you noted, this is valid syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to understand is an `UPDATE` statement may also use features like `JOIN`, where more than one table is present. So you can have something like this:

```
UPDATE X
SET col1 = Y.colA
FROM X
INNER JOIN Y ON X.col2 = y.colB
```

Now we have two tables involved, and so the `X` next to `UPDATE` tells us which table we are targeting.

Of course, we would still prefer `X.col1` over just `col1` in the `SET` clause. Make that change, and the `X` next to the `UPDATE` keyword seems redundant again. However, *it is not legal to target two tables in the same statement*. Therefore, the `X` next to `UPDATE` tells the server what references are legal targets in the `SET` clause. It's especially useful when using aliases (which you should pretty much always do):

```
UPDATE x
SET x.col1 = y.colA, x.col3 = y.colC
FROM VeryLongTableNameA x
INNER JOIN VeryLongTableNameB y ON x.col2 = y.colB
```

Technically, you *could* still simplify the language to remove the `X` next to `UPDATE`. The query compiler could infer the target based on the `SET` clause, and multiple or ambiguous targets would fail to compile, producing a syntax error. But that's not how the language works. When you want the full queries to typically complete in single-digit milliseconds, making things even a wee bit easier for the compiler does have value.

Answer (score 0):

What doesn't make sense?

This is an `update` statement on `X`.  The `X` in `update x` is really the table alias defined by the `from` clause.